# uMatrix How to Whitelist url

Tags: google-chrome

I recently started using the [uMatrix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umatrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf) extension for Google Chrome and it has been one of the best extensions I use, I really like the extension however I have been having one slight issue that is rather annoying.

Is there a way to have uMatrix always allow specific urls; such as all instances of "ytimg.com"? Every time a website wants to load a YouTube video whether it be [Example 1](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/12/18/android-polices-picks-for-the-20-best-android-apps-of-2015/) or [Example 2](http://gizmodo.com/11-of-the-weirdest-videos-on-youtube-1580781007) I have to open umatrix, enable the scripts and frames from youtube.com and ytimg.com every time. Is there a way to have websites of my choosing always be enabled, such as always allowing every instance of youtube.com no matter which website I am on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can, either via the *My Rules* tab in the Dashboard or using the matrix. In the upper left corner there's a blue cell designating the current scope of the matrix. Click on it, select the asterisk and allow whatever you want.

Whatever you allow in the global (*) scope is allowed everywhere and essentially whitelisted.

[image: uMatrix menu]

Also check out the [Very bare walkthrough for first time users](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/wiki/Very-bare-walkthrough-for-first-time-users) over at the uMatrix wiki for more information.

Comment: Thank you!  I really have loved the functionality umatrix has brought and now that I know how to do this it will be even better.  Thank you again.

Comment: I am not seeing a way to do what is requested in the question.  I cannot see a way to allow "\*.wired.com".  If I go to "my rules" I do not see a way to Create A New Rule such as "\*.wired.com".